# Search MySQL for Pound/Number Sign (#)

Tags: mysql, search, numbers, sign

I need to search for # in my mysql database. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '#%'
```

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '[#]%'
```

None of them work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%#%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[.#.]]'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[.number-sign.]]'
```

This regular expression simply means to check the `#` at the very beginning of the value of `column` attribute

You can change the regular expression to something like this `'^[[.#.]]{1}[[:digit:]]+$'` OR `'^[[.number-sign.]]{1}[[:digit:]]+$'` which would mean that `#` should be followed by digits(only)

check this url

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
```

and search for `[.characters.]` it also provides with a couple of examples for you to understand.